# Ubuntu says installation is successful, but prompts for installation again after restarting

Tags: boot, system-installation

Some preface: 
I bought an Acer laptop that had Windows 10 installed and I decided to completely wipe its hard drive so all the memory can be used for Ubuntu. However, I accidentally wiped a part of my hard drive after I installed Ubuntu successfully (to be more specific, I wiped away the memory in /dev/sda2) and I am trying to reinstall again. In addition, I am doing a manual boot from a USB drive. However, the problem is that it says the installation is sucessful and that I need to reboot, but when I do, it takes me right back to the grub installation page (where I have to choose options like Install Ubuntu, Try Ubuntu, do an OEM install, etc.).

Here are some [images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTBvF.jpg) of my BIOS setup.

Comment: Run boot-repair: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I have done a boot-repair and said the repair was successful, but the install is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Dumb question: Have you removed the pen drive after the installation? If don't, it's a normal thing, because you're booting from pen drive again.
Otherwise, boot from the pen drive and verify the health of your installation.
Try:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Then, update us here with the output.

Comment: I did remove it, but when I did, it says there is no bootable device.

Comment: The GNU grub loads?

Comment: If GNU grub is where I choose to install or try Ubuntu, then yes, it loads.

Comment: Let me understand just one thing. You unplugged your pen drive and it stills shows you the screen to install or try ubuntu? That's weird. One way to solve it is boot from a pen drive with Ubuntu and install gparted. In Gparted, format your entire disk to ext4, if don't have any files you want to backup. Then reboot your system with the pen drive still sticked to a USB port. Now install again. Another thing, maybe the partition is not mounted or grub is corrupted. Boot from a pen drive with Ubuntu, choose the try option and follow up this tutorial to restore grub.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I meant while the pen drive was plugged in. Sorry for the confusion.